# Vite specific configuration

Tags: vite

Can I somehow make vite watch the folder where the vue files are and build those files in another folder with the same structure with js, css without index.html?

So far, such a structure has come out, but of course it does not work:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import legacy from '@vitejs/plugin-legacy';
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url';

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
    return {
        plugins: [
            vue(),
            legacy({
                targets: ['defaults', 'not IE 11'],
            }),
        ],
        base: '/',
        publicDir: "/static_mpa/",

        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.ts'],
            alias: {
                '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./static_mpa', import.meta.url))
            }
        },

        build: {
            brotliSize: false, // отчёт о размере файлов
            minify: 'terser',
            outDir: 'static_test',
            assetsDir: './',
            rollupOptions: {
                output: {
                    entryFileNames: '[name].js',
                }
            }
        },
    }
});
```